# How to MFDeploy a configuration file

Tags: .net-micro-framework, netduino

Colleagues and users testing various features in a program use MFDeploy to install for example "MyApp.exe" onto their Netduino +2. This method works great. Is there a way to also MFDeploy a "MyApp.config" text file so they can set their specific network criteria (like Port#) or other program preferences? Obviously, more robust preferences can be set from desktop software or web app AFTER the connection is established.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several days researching, I could not find a viable means of transferring a config file via MFDeploy. Decided to add a "/install" command line option to the desktop app:

```
cncBuddyUI.exe [/help|/?] [/reset] [/discover] [/install:[axisA=X|Y] ,port=9999]] 

/help|/?    Show this help/usage information
/reset      Create new default software configuration
/discover   Listen for cncBuddyCAM broadcasting IPAddress & Port (timeout 30 secs)
/install    Install hardware specific settings on Netduino+2 SDCard.
    port     Network port number (default=80)
    axisA    Slave axisA motor signals to X or Y axis
```

During "/install" mode, once cncBuddyCAM (Netduino app) network connects to cncBuddyUI (desktop app), the configuration parameters are transmitted and written onto the SDCard (\SD\config.txt).
Every warm boot now reads \SD\config.txt at startup and loads the configuration parameters into the appropriate application variables.

After several weeks of usage, I find this method preferable and easier to customize. Check out [cncBuddy](https://github.com/osstekz/cncBuddy) on Github.